# Influxdb data plotted with Grafana graph and millisecond resolution

Tags: c++, grafana, influxdb

I am plotting some data saved with Infuxdb using Grafana charting.
Timestamp is saved with `std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::nanoseconds>(mTimestamp.time_since_epoch()).count().`
Looking at the raw data with `influx -precision rfc3339` I can see the data is saved with more than millisecond resolution: `2020-05-07T16:04:02.2767688Z`.
But when I plot the chart I see the data is plotted with 10 ms resolution steps. I cannot find how chart with higher resolution, i.e. 1 ms resolution.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved setting 1ms value in the `GROUP BY` `time` field. Anything better?

Answer (score 0):

I think obtaining "more than millisecond resolution" in Grafana from InfluxDB is not simple. I had a similar question and it was answered by Jan Garaj here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62495269/12921500

Apparantly Grafana is hardcoded to query InfluxDB data up to only millisecond precision (can be seen in the code [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/36fd746c5df1438f27aa33fc74b24be77debc7ff/public/app/plugins/datasource/influxdb/datasource.ts#L364)). There is also a feature request [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6252) which is open, but isn't a simple option at the moment.